# Why does this player not have a straight?

Tags: poker-texas-holdem

I'm relatively new to poker so bare with me.

Community cards: J, Q, K, 2, 4
P1: A,6
P2: Q,Q

A site determined that P2 won with three of the kind. Is this wrong? How does player P1 not win with a straight by playing only 1 hole card? The way this was graded confuses me!

Comment: P1 does not have a straight.  P1s best hand is A,K,Q,J,6

Comment: can you explain when you are allowed to play one hole card?

Comment: Upon a second reading; I do not think this is a duplicate. The linked question and answer never defines what a "straight" is; and the quesiton/confusion here seems to be over what counts as a valid straight.

Comment: @StartPlayer As the one who wrote the answer to that, I updated the descriptions to clarify that such a hand is NOT a straight.

Comment: Personally I think it would be better to not try to fit this question under the umbrella of the other question. Even though the asker didn't realize it; the question was one of poker terminology (not knowing what qualified as a "straight") while the linked question is one of how to properly compare 2 hands to determine which is better. Just because the answer to the other question can be made more comprehensive to include the definition of a straight doesn't mean that this is a duplicate question.

Comment: I edited the subject to match the primary focus of the body, and removed the one sentence near the end of the body that is actually asking a different question (one that would be a duplicate of the linked question).

Comment: With the edits I agree that this question should be reopened as it is now clear about what is being asked and not a duplicate of what is a winning hand.

Comment: I felt the question was asking why hand B beat hand A.  the question was not (why do they not have a straight) but why did they not win WITH a straight.  What I felt was a duplicate question covers what is a straight.

Comment: @moam8732 What you think of is called *round-the-corner straight*. This does exist as a variant in house rules, but is not a part of the official poker rules. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_poker_hand

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that a straight cannot be made with an Ace in the middle of the straight. Ace can be considered either the lowest card (forming a straight with A, 2, 3, 4, 5); or the highest card (forming a straight with 10, J, Q, K, A). It cannot be both low and high at the same time; so J, Q, K, A, 2 is not a straight.

In the case of this hand, player 1's best hand is A,K,Q,J,6; which doesn't form any combination; it is simply an Ace-high hand.

https://wiki.c2.com/?PokerGame

> The ace is the highest-ranking card in the deck, followed by the king, the queen, the jack, and the numbered cards in order. The 2 is the lowest-ranking card. In some hands, however (such as the straight and straight flush), an ace can be used as a "1" card - Ace, 2, 3, 4, 5 is a valid straight, as is 10-Jack-Queen-King-Ace. **The ace cannot be in the middle; one cannot form a straight with Queen-King-Ace-2-3.**

[Another source](https://www.888poker.com/magazine/poker-terms/straight), since there is no one difinitive rulebook for Poker to cite:

> The best possible straight in poker is the Ace-high straight (TJQKA) often referred to as “broadway”. The Ace can also be used to formulate the lowest possible straight A2345, often referred to as “the wheel”. **Note however that it is not possible for the Ace to appear in the middle of a made straight. I.e. QKA23 is actually just Ace-high, not a straight.**

Note that you never get to choose "how many" hole cards you play. You always play a total of 5 cards; whichever 5 of the 7 options give you the best hand. IF player 1 had been holding a 10 instead of a 2, then player 1 would automatically play 10, J, Q, K, A; and would win the hand because of the straight, playing 1 hole card as you suggest.